# What is the fastest iteration over a large network instance of DiGraph networkx?

Tags: python, algorithm, iteration, networkx

I'm writing a class which inherits from DiGraph.py from the open source networkx package in python.

In some method in my class, I need to search for nodes with certain degrees (outdegrees or indegrees for directed graph) and return them.

This class is to be used with a data mining project\natural language processing , its going to be used on extremely large networks. what I need is a fast implementation of the method described (return list of nodes with a certain out degree or certain in degree).

There a couple of things already defined in the super class:
1. a method `network.outdegree()` :
returns a dictionary with node keys and outdegree values.

```
{'school': 4, 'middle school': 0, 'university': 0, 'commercial': 0, 'private': 5, 'institution': 2, 'high school': 0, 'college': 0, 'elementary school': 0, 'central': 0, 'company': 0, 'public': 3, 'bank': 2}
```

1. a method which is

network.out_degree_iter()

```
<generator object out_degree_iter at 0x02EEB328>
```

I don't know how to use this method, If someone can explain how that is used, i will be grateful.

3.I have an attribute network.nodes which is a list of all nodes in my network.

Question: I can iterate over all the nodes and return the ones with outdegree 2 for example, by doing a list comprehension on network.nodes, or I can iterate over my dictionary and return a list of nodes with values 2, or maybe use the `out_degree_iter()` which I don't know how is that used or how is that different from iterating over dictionary items in a for loop ( for k,v in dict.iteritems())?? Which one of these would be faster for a very large network of nodes and edges and WHY??

Thanks

Comment: a generator object is an iterator, it should be used with a for loop. e.g. for a in network.out_degree_iter(): print a. alternatively, list(network.out_degree_iter()) should make a list out of the generator.

Comment: Depending on the size of the project, you may also have to consider whether all the data will fit in available memory.  If you end up having to page to get at some of the data, that can provide significant overhead.  I don't know enough about the DiGraph class to help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the out_degree_iter() method with a list comprehension as you proposed.  Here is how:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.DiGraph(nx.gnp_random_graph(1000,0.001))
t1=[n for n,k in G.out_degree_iter() if k==2
```

The fastest way requires accessing the internal data structure:

```
t2=[n for n,nbrs in G.succ.items() if len(nbrs)==2]
```

For in-degree us in_degree_iter() and G.pred.items().

Here are some timings

```
In [41]: %timeit t1=[n for n,k in G.out_degree_iter() if k==2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 368 us per loop

In [42]: %timeit s2=[n for n,nbrs in G.succ.items() if len(nbrs)==2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 198 us per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterators are better for large graphs because you don't construct a copy of the dictionary. How about something like this:

```
list_of_2 = []
for g in G.out_degree_iter():
    if g[1]==2:
        list_of_2.append(g[0])
```

Or,

```
list_of_2 = map(lambda x:x[0],filter(lambda x:(x[1]==2),G.out_degree_iter()))
```